# Docker: not found

Tags: docker

I started having this issue today after macOS High Sierra update.

I went ahead and uninstalled docker via Docker > Preferences.

Installed fresh docker and I still can't get the following command to work

```
docker info
```

It works for root user, but not for my user.

Comment: If you run `type docker` as root, that'll show you where it's finding the executable. You can then check whether that location is in your `PATH` as a regular user, and adjust your regular user's dotfiles appropriately.

Comment: That said, I'd argue that this is more of a question for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), being about configuring your operating system (in a way that could be relevant to *any* software's installation, rather than being specific to any development-only tooling), as opposed to a question about writing code or use of tools which are exclusively for that purpose.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428269/8644294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue in docker for mac https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2357

Apparently new version of H Sierra, does not work properly with docker for mac

Comment: Correct, googled that later on myself. Managed to fix it with fresh re-install.

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/47]

After setting docker.sock path, I could not find com.docker.docker.

So, instead of docker for mac, I installed docker using brew command, 
then run

```
brew cask install docker
```

Now, click on the whale icon and click allow for all the successive prompts.  Now, try re running the build with the tag you want.

```
docker build -t <name> .
```

Now, this works as expected. please try. This resolved my problem. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try install using brew

```
brew install docker
```