# Docker command not found when running on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, command-line, command

I'm trying to run the below code as instructed in the [docker-graphite-statsd](https://github.com/graphite-project/docker-graphite-statsd):

```
docker run -d\
 --name graphite\
 --restart=always\
 -p 80:80\
 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004\
 -p 2023-2024:2023-2024\
 -p 8125:8125/udp\
 -p 8126:8126\
 graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
```

It gives this error:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name graphite --restart=always -p 80:80 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004 -p 2023-2024:2023-2024 -p 8125:8125/udp -p 8126:8126 graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
sudo: docker: command not found
```

This is on a Mac. I tried `brew install docker` but it made no difference.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Follow steps from official site : https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: Run `brew doctor` it'll help you to detect the error in the installation.

Comment: I installed it from the official link for my new M1 and the terminal can't find the docker command. Anyone else with this issue? `https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/` the `brew doctor` didn't help.

Comment: it does work just fine on the app, it seems to be running my container if I do it from there, just not from the terminal zsh on my mac m1

Comment: see my answer to fix the issue if your terminal can't find the command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009138/docker-command-not-found-when-running-on-mac/71876799#71876799

Comment: If you installed the .dmg package on Mac, make sure that you opened the docker desktop app and grant the required privileges and permissions to it, once, before running the docker command.

Comment: Docker on Mac is such a pain in the you-know-where...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run **brew list** which will show a list of all your installed Homebrew packages.

But it's highly recommended to install docker using below link on your mac :

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: I did install from the link (no brew) and it still can't find the command!?

Comment: For me, the `docker` command didn't become available until I ran the Docker desktop app. Simply following the .dmg's instructions to copy Docker into the Applications folder wasn't enough. In other words, you'll have to actually run Docker to complete the installation process.

Comment: @CalebKoch I've run the Docker Desktop app, and still no `docker` command.

Comment: Can't run the desktop app because I literally don't have a desktop. How can this be done in the shell (ssh)?

Comment: I still can't make this work as it used to (the `docker` CLI becomes available only when you're running Docker Desktop). I've uninstalled and reinstalled now many times in a row, via both the Homebrew cask and the downloaded dmg from the Docker website.  
  
All I can think is that something isn't getting cleaned up to the point that reinstallation takes care of enabling the CLI as part of app startup.  
  
As a workaround, I just did `echo PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.docker/bin"`, and now I can run `docker` commands. I suppose they'll fail if Docker Desktop isn't also running.

Answer (score 198):

I'm afraid you need to add `docker` command to your PATH manually. It can be done through profile file. As `ZSH` is now a default shell on MacOS, it would go to `~/.zprofile` file:

```
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
# Add Docker Desktop for Mac (docker)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/"
```

Comment: That's the only solution here. Thank you!

Comment: Note that recent versions of docker install the CLI in `$HOME/.docker/bin`, and these are just symlinks to the bins in `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/`

Comment: Be sure to add the `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/` in `~/zshrc` or `bashrc`. I was adding it with an `EXPORT` command but that only set the `PATH` for my current terminal session.

Comment: That's the solution which fixed it after visiting more than 10 links in internet. Thanks

Comment: Why this answer is still not considered as accepted answer? The solution works great.

Comment: and then run "exec zsh" to activate the changes.

Answer (score 39):

After installing docker using Homebrew, start the Docker daemon by searching for Docker in the Application folder in Finder and running it.

I had to run the following from terminal after doing the above:
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

Now run "docker --version" from terminal and it should give the desired result.

Reference : https://www.cprime.com/resources/blog/docker-on-mac-with-homebrew-a-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 32):

There's is likely a better solution but this worked for me (macOS):

Edit your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`, depending on which one you use

```
vi ~/.zshrc # or ~/.bashrc
```

In my case `.zshrc`

```bash
# ~/.zshrc
...

alias docker="/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker"

...
```

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

this should work now

```
docker --version
```

This works because we're aliasing `docker` to the executable located in `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker`.

Comment: Instead of an alias, I'd use a symlink so scripts can also find it. eg: `ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker ~/bin/`

Comment: From Docker Desktop version 4.18, default "CLI utility" installation PATH is `$HOME/.docker/bin`, than instead of using `/usr/local/bin/docker`, you must use `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.docker/bin`, and it worked. Docker made this change because installing "CLI" to the `/usr/local/bin` PATH required root permissions.

Answer (score 17):

`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/"`

is the only solution works for me

Tried the `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.docker/bin"` but failed, although it's the symlink to real location and I can run docker from it in Terminal

Comment: Laptop OS is Mac 13.3.0

Comment: it 's on so work for me on Mac Montery. thanks

Answer (score 13):

By default Docker CLI tools are installed under $HOME/.docker/bin You need to manually add $HOME/.docker/bin to your PATH .

You can change this by going to `Docker --> Settings --> Advanced --> change from user to system`
After choosing system Docker CLI tools are installed under /usr/local/bin.

This is persistent method and you won't have to export.

If you don't want to change settings, exporting this in the terminal where docker will be used does the did.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/"
```

Comment: every time Docker has a new update, you need to run this code to re-add to the path somehow for me on my Mac.

Answer (score 9):

This command helped me:

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker --version
```

Check version after that:

```
docker --version
```

Comment: `ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~ % docker --version` returns `Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243` but I still can't run anything `docker run hello-world` or `docker ps` only results in 
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: I added `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin` to the `$PATH` after confirming this command worked

Answer (score 8):

As of docker desktop mac (in my case v4.18, Apple Silicon version), the default installation is

- no longer => `/usr/local/bin`
- now => `$HOME/.docker/bin`

See Docker Desktop > Settings > Advanced, which provides two options:

- System, and
- User, with User being default

In the case of System, the location is in the default macOS path. In the case of User, you'll need to add an entry to your path.

> System: (Requires password)
> Docker CLI tools are installed under `/usr/local/bin`.

> User: Docker CLI tools are installed under `$HOME/.docker/bin`. Note: You need to manually add `$HOME/.docker/bin` to your PATH.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to add it to your path. If your shell is `bash`, here are the steps you need to take:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then, add your Docker binary path (mine there, for example):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/"
```

then reload the configuration & test with:

```
source ~/.bash_profile && docker --v
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Homebrew's docker doesn't install /usr/local/bin/docker or the /Applications/Docker.app any more on 10.13.

You have to download the Docker Desktop for Mac application from the docker.com site above and install it.

Comment: I did install from the link/official site (no brew) and it still can't find the command!?

Comment: This is no longer true. ´´´brew install --cask docker´´´ does indeed install docker to /usr/local/bin/docker and does make a Docker application in /Applications

Comment: I ended up with 1) installing from the link/official site (no brew) and then 2) `brew install docker` – and the issue has gone.

Answer (score 5):

If you successfully installed docker using the official package, the command should be available under `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

That directory might not yet be in your $PATH, so you could try adding it, run:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

this adds `/usr/local/bin` to the front of your `PATH`.

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57231241/1601580

---

Detais:

Check docker is not there:

```
docker
zsh: command not found: docker
```

Check what PATH is:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/brandomiranda/.opam/__coq-platform.2022.01.0~8.15~beta1/bin:/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then add PATH (To set it for current shell and all processes started from current shell use `export`):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Check what I added to Path:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/Users/brandomiranda/.opam/__coq-platform.2022.01.0~8.15~beta1/bin:/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Seems that `/usr/local/bin` wasn't in my path. Probably odd? Seems odd to me...why isn't it there?

Comment: Nope. I installed and ran Docker desktop, and there is no `/usr/local/bin` at all. In fact, `sudo find /usr -name docker` finds nothing!

Comment: As of November 2023, docker installed from the official site https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/ is NOT under /usr/local/bin/docker !! I can't find where my docker command is

Answer (score 5):

I started getting this error when my Docker Desktop (in `macOS Sonoma`) was updated to `4.25.0` version.

[image]

Turns out, I have to add `$HOME/.docker/bin` to the PATH on versions `4.18` and later, because Docker CLI tools are installed in the user directory now as shown in the settings below:

[image]

### Steps:

1. Check the shell you're using.

   ```bash
   echo $0
   ```

   For eg: I'm using `bash`.

   [image]
2. I'm using `bash`, so I ran this command

   ```bash
   vim ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   But if you're using `zsh`, you'd run this instead

   ```
   vim ~/.zshrc
   ```
3. Add this to the file

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/.docker/bin
   ```
4. Hit `Esc`, type `:wq` and hit enter to save and quit.
5. In order to pick up the changes to your profile, either close and reopen the terminal, or manually source your respective `~/.profile`. For my case, I ran this command

   ```bash
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

It starts working at this point:

[image]

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/#advanced-1

Answer (score 4):

With the new version Docker Desktop 4.21.1, by default the desktop app engine (Macos) will setup Docker in `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker` but this location can be changed by the advance settings

1. Change the advance settings from user to System (this will change the location to `/usr/local/bin`)
2. Run the command `docker --version`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

============================================================================

If you are using a Rancher desktop on MAC (mac OS Ventura) and facing this issue

============================================================================

1. vi ~/.zshrc
2. Add below line at the very end

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rd/bin:$PATH"
```

3. Save and exit
4. On the terminal execute the following command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

5. check if docker command is available now

```
docker ps
```

Answer (score 3):

**MacOS** Sonoma 14.3.1 ,
**Docker** 4.28.0

Inside Docker desktop, go to **Settings** > **Advanced Settings**

You'll see `Choose how to configure the installation of Docker's CLI tools`

I changed it from `User` to `System`. It resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a MacOS Big Sur running on the Intel chip.

I installed the Docker desktop by installing the .dmg file from here:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/

I am using .zsh (with the Warp terminal) and I kept getting this error: "zsh: command not found: docker" when I was typing in any command like "docker --version"

So I ran the following command in my zsh terminal:

echo PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.docker/bin" >> ~/.zshrc

I then restarted my terminal and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install `docker` with following command on **Mac**:

```
brew install docker-machine docker
```

Comment: re-installing using a different method may lead to conflicting versions. It´s better to solve the previous installation. Or if you suggest this new installation as a solution, then you should provide the cleaning-up steps before installation IMO

Comment: agreed with the comment above. This sort of approach only messes up things even more

Answer (score 0):

So to install images, instead of

```
/bin/docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

use

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used Homebrew to install Docker, you should open it in Applications, confirm the precautions, and add it to the background applications.

Then the Docker app is started, and you can use any commands of docker XXX.

Answer (score 0):

Commands to fix the issue:

```bash
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.*
cd /usr/local/bin
chmod 0755 dock*
```

Then

- quit Docker Desktop;
- reopen Docker Desktop, probably wait for a minute for changes to be reflected.

Taken from the following [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnNRuKS6RIU).

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. This was the only way I was able to solve the problem. One additional note: I had to go into Privacy & Security and give terminal full disk access to successfully delete all the Docker metadata in ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.*

Answer (score 0):

execute following command in a cli

```
brew link docker
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many places from where the value of $PATH variable is influenced.
Following is a way to add the path to it permanently in zsh:

1. Open the terminal
2. `cd /etc/paths.d`
3. Create a new file with any name. For instance you want to create a path for docker then `sudo vi dockerpath`
4. Paste your path in this file `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin`
5. Write and close. Press esc and `:wq`
6. Open a new terminal to check if the newly added path is present. `echo $PATH`