# cannot find docker client executable on macOS

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am trying to inspect an image using the dive command, `dive ubuntu:latest`. I already have dive successfully installed via `brew install dive` but I still cannot inspect the image and simply getting the cannot find docker client executable error.

I expected to the contents of the ubuntu image that I was trying to inspect. My problem was solved by exporting the Docker environment in my path, a hack I found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71923962/11040969

Comment: I would suggest to install Docker Desktop, so that you can use both the IDE and the command line on your terminal according to your preference.

Comment: I actually had docker desktop installed. The error might've been caused by something else